# Deleting JSON object inside an array, when the object has key value pair where the value is ""

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

How would I delete THE OBJECT a key value pair is in if the value of one of the keys in the object is "" 
ex. **("name": "")** from a JSON file?
 
For the life of me I can't figure out why the first 2 objects would get erased and not the last one.
I assume it has something to do with "" but I'm not able to put my thumb on why.

```
[
 {"name":{},"mail":{},"msg":{},"timestamp":1575240647577,"_id":"9ZCckYie9I3XUmKC"},
 {"name":"james 
   smith","mail":"jamessmith@gmail.com","msg":"hi","timestamp":1575241232158,"_id":"fVWl1bufhCYb9rcQ"},
{"location":"Miami","timestamp":1575240647577,"_id":"9ZCckYie9I3XUmKC"},

 {"name":"","mail":"","msg":"","timestamp":1575240990509,"_id":"AzePVvAbc0ZQgJe9"}
]
```

```
databaseQuery()
async function databaseQuery() {
    const response = await fetch('/api')
    const data = await response.json()
    let index

      for (let item of data) {
        if (!item.location) {
          index = data.indexOf(item)
          data.splice(index, 1)
        }
```

edit: sorry I didn't explain my problem correctly. I meant to ask for guidance on how the whole object itself can be deleted.

Comment: index is changed in the for...of loop. It's to index each individual object so I can slice that piece of data.

Comment: Is this actually a JSON file or a database call?  You say JSON file, but you have `databaseQuery()` as the function name. This is weird, as you've got two different representations of the data; a string and an object. `name:{}` and `name:"james smith"`. `""` is a perfectly acceptable value, so if that's what's in the database that's what you're going to get back.

Comment: Next time ask how to remove an object from an array.  Your question was not at all clear.

Comment: What is the part of `async function databaseQuery() {...`  in this question ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you iterate on a collection you are editing at the same time.

Instead use the `filter` method:

```
const withLocation = data.filter(x => "location" in x && x.location !== "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way your loop is running.

In the first iteration of the loop, you have an index of 0, so the very first item in your array gets removed.

In the second iteration of your array, you get an index of 1, so the last item is removed (since you only have 2 items left in your array at this point).

Since the last item was removed, it doesn't have any more items to loop over.

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear.

if you just want to delete elements in a JSON simply use Delete => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

sample code

```js
let xyz = { "name"     : ""
          , "mail"     : ""
          , "msg"      : ""
          , "timestamp": 1575240990509
          , "_id"      : "AzePVvAbc0ZQgJe9"
          } 

for (let elm in xyz) {
  if (xyz[elm]==='') delete xyz[elm];
}

console.log( xyz )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach could be something like that

```
const arrayWithLocation = data.filter(x => x.location)

const arrayWithoutLocation = data.filter(x => !x.location)
```